# After fanyimpute installation I am facing this error at the time import

Tags: python-3.x, fancyimpute

Error when importing the `fancyimpute` library:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fancyimpute import KNN
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

I am facing this error:

```
Using Tensorflow backend.
C:\Users\userName\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: 
FutureWarning: Passing(type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; 
in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype(["qint8", np.int8, 1)])
```

Comment: Hi, please, put here the code and error as a text, not as an image.

Comment: You have a `FutureWarning`, not an error.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `tensorflow` of `jupyter` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is only `FutureWarning`, which means that some library uses something in `tensorflow`, that will not be supported in *future* versions of `tensorflow`, but it should work without problems, unless there is some other error that is not shown in the screenshot.